# Colorbox with scroll allowed, div in the background fixed

Tags: scroll, position, overlay, colorbox, fixed

I'm trying to mantain a container div behind my colorbox fixed while the user scrolls  inside the colorbox itself.
I Google´d about it and found, quoting *Jake Moore*:

Example:

```
$().bind('cbox_open', function(){
$('body').css({overflow:'hidden'}); }).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
$('body').css({overflow:'auto'}); });

$(".iframe").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
```

But the previously aint working for me, the scroll locks in the div behind but also in the colorbox, so the user cant scroll anywhere!
I am guessing the `iframe` has something to do with it since im calling colorbox this way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".some-link", function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.colorbox({
        onComplete: function(){
            some other stuff()
            $.colorbox.resize();
            $('body').css({overflow:'hidden'})
        },
        onCleanup: function(){
            some other stuff()
            $('body').css({overflow:'hidden'})
        },
        href: url,                
    });
});
```

Any ideas? Is there any other way to disable the scroll within a div, but allowing it in another one ?

Im using colorbox with something like infinite-scroll so when the user scrolls down more information keeps showing up (div boxes actually). Those boxes are the ones that fire the colorbox, ".some-link" is a link within the box.

Hope my english is tuned. Regards! Agustin